# One column in a table contains multiple email addresses. How to add new rows to the table for each email address found in the column?

Tags: sql-server

The emails in the column are formatted like this. Comma delimited, quote encapsulated, with surrounding brackets:

```
["1stemail@gmail.com","2ndemail@gmail.com","3rdemail@gmail.com"]
```

The number of emails in the column is variable.  This column can have zero emails or hundreds of emails.

Looking to add a new row to the table for each email in this column, if an email exists in the column.

I am admittedly in over my head.  I don't know how to do this but I would like to learn.

Each row will contain an identity column.

My first thought was to find how many emails are in the email column by counting the @ characters.

```
  SELECT 
     [email_column], 
     LEN([email_column]) - LEN(REPLACE([email_column], '@', '')) as cnt
  FROM tablename
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I thought I'd try to use a WHILE loop using the cnt to extract each email from each row.  This is where I get in trouble.  I don't know if I need to first add a new email column for the max amount of emails found in the statement above, then use a loop to extract the existing emails from the original email column, placing them singly in the added email columns, and then UNPIVOT?

Or is it possible to UNPIVOT without first separating the emails into separate columns?

Comment: *"are formatted like ... Comma delimited, quote encapsulated, with surrounding brackets:"* That's a JSON array; why not use `OPENJSON`?

Comment: That isn't unpivoting either. Unpivoting is when you convert *multiple* columns into rows. Such as converting the columns `tel1`, `tel2`, `tel3` into a single `tel` column, with 1 row per (non-`NULL`) "tel" column.

Comment: SQL is not about multiple values in one column, so why would you want to make it worse? What's the purpose of this table and why do you want to add a new row containing every email address

Comment: Do you want to add one row per email, or one giant row containing every email or what. Please attach a table definition, some rows and how the final result should be

Comment: This is the scenario I am faced with.  The data is already in this format.  I am trying to "fix" it by creating a new row for each email address instead of having them stored in one column.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping, I suggest using [`cross apply`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) with [`openjson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename   (
  Id int identity(1,1),
  email_column nvarchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO tablename (email_column) VALUES
('["1stemail@gmail.com","2ndemail@gmail.com","3rdemail@gmail.com"]'),
(''),
(null),
('["1stemail@gmail.com"]');
```

Then, create another table to hold the properly-normalized data:

```
CREATE TABLE emailAddresses(
  emailAddress nvarchar(1000), 
  originalId int
);
```

And populate it using `insert...select`:

```
INSERT INTO emailAddresses(originalId, emailAddress) 
SELECT Id, productTypes.value
FROM tablename 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(NULLIF(email_column, '')) AS productTypes;
```

*Note the usage of `NULLIF` in the query above, this will prevent errors in your query if `email_column` contains an empty string.

Results:

```
emailAddress        originalId
1stemail@gmail.com  1
2ndemail@gmail.com  1
3rdemail@gmail.com  1
1stemail@gmail.com  4
```

You can see a live demo in [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/F677EpoD)

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for the hassle.  I've only used this forum once before, years ago.  I appreciate your reply.

Comment: It might seem silly, but [so] (and other sites in the community) aren't a forum, @caddy ; they're Q&A sites. They actually work very differently to a forum, such as the fact that discussions and opinions aren't actually on-topic.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: @Zohar Peled, I just want to say thanks again.  I just tried using your solution and it worked like a charm, exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!  Have a great day.